# C# Updating a DataGridView/DataSource from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datasource

I'm writing a program that updates user accounts on a MySQL database.  The program is going to be used on multiple computers at once.

Currently I load the MySQL data into a DGV by this and refresh in a similar way;

```
mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM a_Users;", connection); // Query the database
DataSet DS = new DataSet(); // Create new DataSet
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS); // Fill the Dataset with the information gathered above
dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0]; // Set the dgv source to the newly created DataSet
```

and when editing I get the DGV row to a DataRow, and then update the DGV by changing the DataRow like this (from another form);

```
DataRow dr = (dataGridView1.Rows[SelectedRow].DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row; // Get the selected row to a new DataRow
dr["Phone Number"] = PhoneNumber_tb.Text;
```

My problem is, I want to update the DGV with any new/modified rows from the MySQL database every xx seconds, and if modifying a row when this happens the DataRow is then Invalid as the above code re-makes the whole structure.

Is there a way to update the DGV or DGV DataSource and maintain the ability to use the DataRow I pulled for editing?
How can I update the Datasource with any changes from the MySQL database.

I have tried BindingSource and a whole bunch of other things I have googled.

I could find UserID in the DGV then update the row that way, if no answer is found here.

Currently when editing a user, if the DGV refreshes with the SQL Database my edit form will not update the DGV as the DataRow no longer exists where it was.

Comment: I'd turn off the timer that is refreshing the dataset while I was editing a row. Send the changes to the db then turn refreshing back on

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using, works nicely.
Only gets the rows that have been updated since we last checked.  Still using the example in the question to retrieve the Database initially

```
mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM a_Users WHERE DTGModified > " + LastUpdated.ToString() + ";", connection); // Query the database
DataTable DT = new DataTable(); // Create new DataSet
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DT); // Fill the Dataset with the information gathered above
LastUpdated = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"); // Save the time we retrieved the database

foreach (DataRow dr in (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).Rows)
{
    foreach(DataRow DTdr in DT.Rows)
    {
        if (dr["ID"].ToString() != DTdr["ID"].ToString()) continue;

        dr.ItemArray = DTdr.ItemArray;
    }
}
```